# Why my JavaScript functions only works in Index View?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've been working on an ASP.Net application. I have a simple website that has some JavaScript functions in it. When I first run the project it loads the index view and everything works just fine. However when I navigate to another page from my index view the JS functions stop working, even though I added all scripts links and functions in the layout page.

What I tried too is to put the functions:

1. in the `head` tag,
2. before the closing body tag
3. directly after `@Renderbody`
   However none of this worked.

Here's my code

layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Layout</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="~/Scripts/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
</head>


   @RenderBody()
  // Some Html code
<script>

               $("#postIt").click(function () {
                   postIt();
               });
               function postIt() {
                   var usr = $("#username").val();
                   var pwd = $("#password").val();
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "Home/Login",
                       data: {
                           "Username": usr,
                           "Password": pwd
                       },
                       success: function (data) {
                           if (data.result) {
                               JSalert(data.result);
                               reload();
                               //alert(data.message);
                           } else {
                               // unauthorized
                               alert(data.message);
                           }
                       }
                   });
               }

               function JSalert(result) {
                   swal("Congrats!", " Your account is logged in!", "success", 3000, true);
                   setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1700);

               }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the other pages I included at top

```
@{

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I checked page source on the others pages, the js functions exists.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code too? It will hellp to identify the issue more clearly

Comment: Code might not be necessary, but the way you have proposed the question doesn't leave a place for anyone to make a informed answer for you.  "My javascript doesn't work, can you fix it" isn't the best way to inform everyone.  There are many of reasons why your javascript doesn't work.  Does it load correctly in the other pages?  Are there any errors in the console?  Are you building a framework or typescript using webpack with one of dotnet core template?

Comment: Check the console for errors. It most likely the code hasn't been included in the page, or the path to it is wrong when you move to another page

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I checked the Console, I have 0 errors @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Try one thing, Keep your functions above the renderbody

Comment: @AamirAli not working too, but I have to mention that I already have other functions after renderbody, and they are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot the closing head tag as well as the opening body tag in the code you posted. 
Please check again when you fix it

Comment: No mate, it's my fault I didn't copy it with the code.